updating Google Map React center using UseState results in NaN's
I have a Map component in my React project, which receives a prop of a current hotel and is supposed to retrieve and present the hotel's location on a Google Map React Map.
This is the code of my MapView.jsx component so far-
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import MapMarker from "../../../public/svg/MapMarker.svg";

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => (
    <div className='map-marker'>
        <div className='chat-box'>
            <p>{text}</p>
            <div className="chat-arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <img src={MapMarker} alt="Map Marker" />
    </div>
);

export function MapView({ stay }) {
    const [defaultProps, setDefaultProps] = useState({
        center: { lat: 32.5, lng: 34.9 },
        zoom: 15
    });

    const handleApiLoaded = (map, maps) => {
        // use map and maps objects
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (stay && stay.loc && stay.loc.lat && stay.loc.lng) {
            setDefaultProps({
                center: { lat: stay.loc.lat, lng: stay.loc.lng },
                zoom: 15
            });
        }
    }, [stay]);

    return (
        <div className="map-container">
            <h2>Where you'll be</h2>
            <p>{stay.loc.address}</p>
            <div style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }}>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "AIzaSyDMl5nCzylGqvy3ogV2cL1CIxCl7X1b0vQ" }}
                    center={defaultProps.center}
                    defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
                    yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
                    onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => handleApiLoaded(map, maps)}
                >
                    <AnyReactComponent
                        lat={defaultProps.center.lat}
                        lng={defaultProps.center.lng}
                        text="Exact location provided after booking."
                    />
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>

            <a href="#" className="show-more">Show more</a>
        </div>
    );
}

When stay loads I want the location to change to the hotel's location, but the code results in the map not showing and this error occurs-

Why is this error showing? logging the stay loc before using setDefaultProps clearly shows that they are defined so I don't get why there is an NaN.
Is there a changeCenter or updateCenter function that I'm missing?
I've been stuck on this for days and can't find an answer in the documentation...
UPDATE:
this is the stay prop data-

The typeOf stay.loc.lat and lng is number

Can you share the values in the stay object?

Sure, updated it in the question :)

Looks like the issue occurs when the lat value is out of the range. Its value should be between [-90, 90] as seen in docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng.constructor. When trying to set it more than 90 or less than -90, this error throws. So, you might add an if statement there to check if the value is between the range or not

As documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral-Properties, you may set it to 90 or -90 automatically, if it's out of the range

@OnurDoğan AMAZING!
They gave it to use in the demo data so I thought the values are valid there... thank you so much it works now :)))))

The issue is related to the lat value since it was out of the range. The lat value should be between [-90, 90] as seen in the Google Map Documentations. Therefore, when trying to set a value that isn't between the range([-90,90]), it throws this error.
To fix this issue, check whether the lat value is out of the range, and if it's out of the range, then set it to the max(90) or min(-90) automatically as seen in the documentation
Hope, it's clear and helpful

Thanks to @Onur Doğan insight, I changed the values of the lat to be less than 90 or larger than -90 and it fixed the problem :)
